# Graphics card issue or coding problem? THREE.JS webgl

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

So I have created a scene using three.js it used to work perfectly untill today (nothing has changed in the code) but in every browser chrome, firefox, Edge I keep getting the error:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.
```

I suspect this is a graphics card issue can someone confirm?

curiously in chrome I also get an extra error:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error: 0 35715 false gl.getProgramInfoLog THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex
```

Here is the live link (project is unfinished):

https://ui-unicorn.co.uk/game-lesson-1/new-index-2021

Can someone please confirm if the project is broken via code or if the problem is my graphics card?

Kind regards

EDIT: other webgl projects are working fine for me also which is even stranger if it was my graphics card being the issue..

Comment: I suspect there are some race conditions that make it difficult to load the game at all. Often the loading screen never switches over or, when it does, the characters don't appear and no interactions work (though clicking does seem to log correctly).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be an issue with your GPU, having loaded the page myself, there is no obvious error on the page itself. However upon inspecting element on Firefoxs development tools it shows a few messages. These are;

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (500x500) to (256x256).
```

( One of the textures was too big)

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: gl.getProgramInfoLog() C:\fakepath(190,23-154): warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them
```

( several of these but I have no idea what it refers to. )

```
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL: https://ui-unicorn.co.uk/game-lesson-1/js/ifvisible.js Source Map URL: ifvisible.map
```

And this, again I have no idea.

As for the original error, it seems three.module.js runs it's own rendering debugger and flagged errors with the shaders so I would assume that that means there is an issue with the shaders governing light, shadows, models etc.

Comment: Can you confirm the webgl loaded for you? and didn't fail with THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost. the issues you have pointed out shouldn't be making it fail though to be honest im assuming its my graphic card if the project loads for you

Comment: Those are all warnings and the one about source maps isn't meaningful in this context. Warnings can mostly be ignored (though they should be fixed if possible). The main error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: mixer4 is undefined`. As it's an error, and not a warning, fixing it will probably go a ways towards fixing other issues as well

Comment: @user3112634 yeah it loads for me, a little bit slowly but that could be either the laptop I am using or the internet. I saw no other errors/warnings other than the above.

Comment: @Ouroborus I can't seem to reproduce that error may I ask what browser you are using please and how this error came to be

Comment: @user3112634 That was in Firefox. Chrome shows a different error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined at animate`. Altogether, I've only been able to successfully load the game the second time I tried and haven't since.